# JPCT-AE highlight overlapping objects - polygons

Tags: android, opengl-es, jpct

I am using [JPCT AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/) in my 
Android app for drawing polygons of the same color which represent a path that a vehicle have covered. Currently I am using transparency to highlight the areas where polygons overlap but I would like to have those areas more visible by giving them different color like in this picture:

[image]

I guess it can be achieved by writing a shader for this purpose, but I need some guidance. Any help?